# JavaScript deeply nested array v's shallow array splicing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which in turn contain arrays of objects. I wish to filter both the 'top level' (shallow) array and the 'nested' array. In order to maintain a definitive array I have looped through the remoteData and pushed each object into both a definitiveArray and a filteredArr. The idea being that I only ever manipulate the filteredArray.

If I loop through and splice an item out of the filteredArray's shallow array using filteredArray.spice(0, 1) it ONLY affects the filteredArray i.e.  the one I'm trying to manipulate.
If however I try to splice an item out of the filteredArray.nested array using filteredArray[0].Colours.splice(0, 1) it removes the item from both the filteredArray and the definitiveArray.

I'm guessing that this is due to a misunderstanding on my part of how JavaScript's references is working. An explanation and guidance on how to overcome this would be appreciated.

A plnkr is availabe here http://plnkr.co/edit/MKSlTogO3YkzHuKnHmwH

```
remoteData = [
{ Id: 1, Text: 'Item 1', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Red' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Orange' } ] },  
{ Id: 2, Text: 'Item 2', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Yellow' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Green' } ] },
{ Id: 3, Text: 'Item 3', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Blue' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Indigo' } ] },
{ Id: 4, Text: 'Item 4', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Violet' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Red' } ] },
{ Id: 5, Text: 'Item 5', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Orange' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Yellow' } ] },],
definitiveArray = [],
filteredArray = []; 

/*
* splicing an item out of the deeply nested array affects both
*/
len = remoteData.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //push data into both the definitive array and the filter array
    definitiveArray.push(remoteData[i]);
    filteredArray.push(remoteData[i]);
}
console.log(filteredArray[0].Colours.length);   //obviously 2
console.log(definitiveArray[0].Colours.length); //obviously 2

//splice the first item in the first Colours array for ONLY the filteredArray
filteredArray[0].Colours.splice(0, 1);
console.log(filteredArray[0].Colours.length);   //obviously 1
console.log(definitiveArray[0].Colours.length); //also 1 rather than 2 that I expected


/*
* If however I splice an item out of the shallow array, it affects only the filteredArray
*/
console.log(filteredArray.length);   //obviously 5
console.log(definitiveArray.length); //obviously 5

//remove the first item in ONLY the filteredArray
filteredArray.splice(0, 1);

console.log(filteredArray.length);   //obviously 4
console.log(definitiveArray.length); //still 5 as this array has been left unaffected
```

here

Comment: filteredArray and definitiveArray are different array objects. What do you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm expecting that, because they are different array objects, splicing out of one will NOT affect the other. What is actually happening is that splicing out of one IS affecting BOTH.

Comment: I understand you now, both objects inside both arrays are the same object. Yo need to deep copy the objects inside the arrays, by @Shreyas method using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, using the extend method of jQuery or making your own function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of each of the nested arrays.

Here's a simple way to do that -

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //push data into both the definitive array and the filter array
    definitiveArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(remoteData[i])));
    filteredArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(remoteData[i])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think if you have object in array splice or slice keep refrance to object, you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(remoteData))

```js
remoteData = [
{ Id: 1, Text: 'Item 1', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Red' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Orange' } ] },  
{ Id: 2, Text: 'Item 2', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Yellow' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Green' } ] },
{ Id: 3, Text: 'Item 3', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Blue' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Indigo' } ] },
{ Id: 4, Text: 'Item 4', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Violet' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Red' } ] },
{ Id: 5, Text: 'Item 5', Colours: [ { Id: 1, Colour: 'Orange' }, { Id: 2, Colour: 'Yellow' } ] },],
definitiveArray = [],
filteredArray = []; 

/*
* splicing an item out of the deeply nested array affects both
*/
len = remoteData.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //push data into both the definitive array and the filter array
    definitiveArray.push(remoteData[i]);
   
}
filteredArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(definitiveArray))
console.log(filteredArray[0].Colours.length);   //obviously 2
console.log(definitiveArray[0].Colours.length); //obviously 2

//splice the first item in the first Colours array for ONLY the filteredArray
filteredArray[0].Colours.splice(0, 1);
alert(filteredArray[0].Colours.length);   //obviously 1
alert(definitiveArray[0].Colours.length); //also 1 rather than 2 that I expected


/*
* If however I splice an item out of the shallow array, it affects only the filteredArray
*/
console.log(filteredArray.length);   //obviously 5
console.log(definitiveArray.length); //obviously 5

//remove the first item in ONLY the filteredArray
filteredArray.splice(0, 1);

console.log(filteredArray.length);   //obviously 4
console.log(definitiveArray.length); //still 5 as this array has been left unaffected
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```